# Ruby On Rails - Link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with ROR/bootstrap and want this "a" tag and images, to link back to root_path. But can't find a good solution. This is what I got. How to replace href?

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="" style="color:black;">
    <!-- span makes them inline-->
    <span><%= image_tag ".png", height: 30, width: 30, alt: "", style:"margin-top:-5px" %></span>
    |
    <span><%= image_tag ".png", width: 60, height: 30, style:"margin-top:-5px"  %></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the following approaches:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_url %>" style="color:black;">
  <!-- span makes them inline-->
  <span>
    <%= image_tag ".png", height: 30, width: 30, alt: "", style:"margin-top:-5px" %>
  </span>
  |
  <span>
    <%= image_tag ".png", width: 60, height: 30, style:"margin-top:-5px"  %>
  </span>
</a>
```

or provide a block to [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to root_url, class: "navbar-brand", style: { color: "black" } do %>
  <!-- span makes them inline-->
  <span>
    <%= image_tag ".png", height: 30, width: 30, alt: "", style:"margin-top:-5px" %>
  </span>
  |
  <span>
    <%= image_tag ".png", width: 60, height: 30, style:"margin-top:-5px"  %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

I'd strongly recommend going with the latter, as the Rails way of doing things. Let me know how you get on - any questions or comments, let me know!

Comment: @meister - did this do it for you? Give me a shout if you have any questions at all!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a block inside [Link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
<%= link_to root_url, :class => 'navbar-brand' do %>
  <span><%= image_tag ".png", height: 30, width: 30, alt: "", style:"margin-top:-5px" %></span>
  |
  <span><%= image_tag ".png", width: 60, height: 30, style:"margin-top:-5px"  %></span>
<% end %>
```

Avoid inline styling as you have currently used, push it into .css files.